# iOS bonding device pinnumber

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

When you first connect to Bluetooth, if you enter the pin number, it will be connected properly and at that moment you will be bonding.
Then, when reconnecting, the window for entering the pin number will not appear and the connection will not be established. Can you continue to enter pin numbers after bonding?

Comment: You will only be prompted again if the bonding is deleted by going into Bluetooth settings and selecting "forget this device"

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the cord from bonding or remove the bonded device?

Comment: Only the user can remove the bonded device from iOS settings.   You can't do it programatically

Comment: Does iOS need to remove the device from the settings and reconnect it??

Comment: Yes, if the user removes the device from settings then iOS will discard the bonding keys and then next time you connect to the device a new bonding will be required

Comment: Thank you for letting us know. Let me think more about how to avoid it.